# How to do a weekly backup of complete Linux machine?

Tags: linux, backup

I'd like to backup a whole remote machine (Linux running CentOS) every week, or month at least. What would be the recommended way to set this up on some local unused PC runing Linux or Windows? Which tool should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually a daily incremental backup would be your best solution. The first run it will backup everything and from there it will just look for changes and keep track what changes were made when. This allows you to have 2-daily or daily backups since your storage will not increase dramatically.

Some common tools for Linux are:

- [bacula](http://www.bacula.org/)
- [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/)

Comment: Compared to rsnapshot, Bacula seems like a more serious tool, better maintained, etc - am I right?

Comment: @danijel Pick the tool that meets your needs...

Comment: @voretaq7 If I knew what tool meets the needs...

Comment: @Danijel Have you defined your requirements? If so compare each tool to your list of requirements (that will probably narrow you down to a small handful of tools), then start looking at additional features, management interfaces, etc. - In this case both Bacula and rsnapshot are popular and maintained, In my environment I happen to use Bacula because (a) I'm familiar with it and comfortable managing it, and (b) it meets my needs better than rsnapshot.

Answer (score 1):

There was a closed question on stackoverflow about this -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208/whats-the-best-linux-backup-solution).

I prefer rsnapshot because of it's simplicity (it does not backup the MBR and the partition table though), and because it's easy to restore backup.

If you need something more enterprise-y, try bacula or amanda. Amanda might be more simple to configure, but they're both pretty complex if you need to backup only one server.

Comment: I only need one server backed up now and then. I am worried that rsnapshot is not well maintained?

Comment: There is almost nothing to be maintained. All it does is make some folders, rsync all data there, and after that just copy-with-hard-links, and rsync over again. This could be done by hand, rsnapshot just makes it a wee-bit easier :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very precise. Some people will use linux some windows. I prefer linux for machine doing and hosting all backups.

If you choose linux you can have very wild choice of tools for doing backups (rsync, rsnapshot, ftp, sftp, bacula and many many more).

If you planning to backup only one machine then I think rsync or rsnapshot will be the best choice.

Comment: Yes, it's only one machine. I'd like to do incremental backup now and then, and to be able to restore machine if it fails some day. Server is Linux and I can backups on Linux too, even I work on and prefer Windows.